# Error when I try to compile project using CMake with SFML library by mingw

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, mingw, sfml

When I want to compile project using CMake with SFML library by mingw (last verison), I catch a lot of strange errors (c++).

CMake code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(MLproject)

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME    Windows)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER     "i686-w64-mingw32-gcc")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER   "i686-w64-mingw32-g++")
SET(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER    "i686-w64-mingw32-windres")
SET(CMAKE_RANLIB         "i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "/usr/i686-w64-mingw32")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

set(SOURCE_EXE src/main.cpp)

set(SOURCE_GAME
  src/Boss/Boss.cpp
  *...*
  src/Game/Game.cpp)

set(SOURCE_UI
  src/UI/ScrollBar/ScrollBar.cpp)

add_library(UI SHARED ${SOURCE_UI})
add_library(Game SHARED ${SOURCE_GAME})

add_executable(main ${SOURCE_EXE})

target_link_libraries(main Game UI
  sfml-graphics sfml-system sfml-windos sfml-audio)
```

Error:

```
CMakeFiles/UI.dir/src/UI/ScrollBar/ScrollBar.cpp.o:ScrollBar.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf14RectangleShapeC1ERKNS_7Vector2IfEE'
CMakeFiles/UI.dir/src/UI/ScrollBar/ScrollBar.cpp.o:ScrollBar.cpp:(.text+0x399): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderStates7DefaultE.....
```

How can I fix it? Does I catch error because have too old C++ version? (Everything is successfully compiled for Linux, but I wanted to make cross-platform)

Comment: If your `UI` library (e.g. `ScrollBar.cpp`) also uses SFML, you *must* link the relevant SFML libraries to the `UI` library: `target_link_libraries(UI PUBLIC sfml-graphics sfml-system sfml-windos sfml-audio)`

Comment: Ohhh, sorry, i shoud use STATIC instead SHARED

Comment: Note, that settings like `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`, `CMAKE_RANLIB`, `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` are normally used in the [toolchain files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html), not in `CMakeLists.txt`. And setting e.g. `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` after the `project()` call is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
CMakeFiles/UI.dir/src/UI/ScrollBar/ScrollBar.cpp.o:ScrollBar.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf14RectangleShapeC1ERKNS_7Vector2IfEE'
```

indicates that the `UI` library uses some SFML components. However, you only link the SFML libraries to the `main` executable, so the library doesn't know where these SFML references are defined. So, you must link any relevant SFML libraries to the `UI` target:

```
target_link_libraries(UI PUBLIC sfml-graphics sfml-system sfml-windos sfml-audio)
```

Use `PUBLIC` here to propagate the SFML libraries to *consumers* of the `UI` target, such as your `main` executable. This removes the need to explicitly link them to `main`. Here is your full CMake with these changes:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(MLproject)

# As commented, consider moving these calls to your toolchain file.
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME    Windows)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER     "i686-w64-mingw32-gcc")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER   "i686-w64-mingw32-g++")
SET(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER    "i686-w64-mingw32-windres")
SET(CMAKE_RANLIB         "i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib")

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "/usr/i686-w64-mingw32")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SOURCE_EXE src/main.cpp)

set(SOURCE_GAME
  src/Boss/Boss.cpp
  *...*
  src/Game/Game.cpp)

set(SOURCE_UI
  src/UI/ScrollBar/ScrollBar.cpp)

add_library(UI SHARED ${SOURCE_UI})
# Link SFML libraries to UI.
target_link_libraries(UI PUBLIC sfml-graphics sfml-system sfml-windos sfml-audio)

add_library(Game SHARED ${SOURCE_GAME})

add_executable(main ${SOURCE_EXE})

# Link Game and UI to the executable, which propagates the SFML libraries from UI also.
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Game UI)
```

Note, many of the calls at the top of your CMake belong in a toolchain file (as commented), often for [cross-compiling](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling). I encourage you to read through the documentation to determine your need for it, and understand how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `_imp___ZN2sf14RectangleShapeC1ERKNS_7Vector2IfEE` went away after adding it to cflags `-DSFML_STATIC`.

C++ creates these "cryptic" names for the linker based on the source code, it is so called "name mangling", so the problem with macro-switch `SFML_STATIC` appeared here when linking.

Comment: Your answer look good but it should be a comment at the validated question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34883480)